# How can the Sub2 copy constructor automatically copy new member variables from Sub1?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

The purpose of Sub2 is to save a snapshot in time of the properties of Sub1.

e.g.:

```
subService.update(sub1);
Sub2 sub2 = new Sub2(sub1);
subService.save(sub2);
```

The problem with the implementation below is that **whenever new member variables are added to Sub1, the programmer has to remember to change the copy constructor in Sub2 to copy the new members from Sub1 to Sub2**.

*How can the Sub2 copy constructor automatically copy new member variables from Sub1?*

### Base class for Sub1 & Sub2:

```
public class Base{

    protected String a;
    protected String b;
    protected String c;
    // ...
    protected String z;

}
```

### Sub1:

```
public class Sub1 extends Base {

    public Sub1(

        String a, 
        String b, 
        String c, 
        // ...
        String z){

        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
        // ...
        this.z = z;

    }

}
```

### Sub2:

```
public class Sub2 extends Base {

    public Sub2(Sub1 s1){

        this.a = s1.getA();
        this.b = s1.getB();
        this.c = s1.getC();
        // ...
        this.z = s1.getZ();         

    }


}
```

Comment: Can you add new member variables to a class in Java? I didn't know that.

Comment: Not dynamically.  I believe he means when the class is modified.

Answer (score 0):

Java has no special concept for copy constructor like C++ does, so it is just another constructor with an argument. You cannot know which members a class has in runtime without using reflection, however I would suggest making Sub1 responsible for storing its current state. For example add store method to Sub1, which would return an array of Strings (its members). Then Sub2 could store those arrays somewhere. When you add a new member to Sub1, change also the store method of Sub1. This way you don't have to touch Sub1.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a "public Sub1 copy()" method on Sub1 (or implement Cloneable).  When you need a snapshot of a Sub1 instance, just invoke copy() or clone().  Get rid of Base/Sub2.